# Regex to replace in files

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have to replace `\` in files when the `\` is not followed by `"`

so I made this regex to find occurrences with SublimeText:

`#\\^"#` but it doesn't work

Do someone has an idea ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `^` to negate a symbol. That works only for groups marked with `[]` to say you mean the opposite. You can use a look-ahead expression to define that the next character may not be a quote: `#\\(?!")#` (Remember to escape the quote, if you use it in a string!)

Comment: ...and be aware of the fact regex delimiters like `#...#` are only necessary in some programming languages (e.g. PHP), so if it still doesn't work, try `\\(?!")`.

Comment: thank you very much :), and indeed I didn't need the `#`since I was searching via SublimeText

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following regex:

```
#[^\\]"#
```

Comment: I think you've got your logic backwards.